# Find the probability limit of sequences of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

[image]

I need to find X such that $X^{}_n \to X$ in probability, thus $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}P(| X^{}_n-X|\ge \varepsilon) = 0$$

When $n\to \infty$  $X^{}_n = 0$ with probability $1$ and I thought $X=0$ is the limit, but with Markov's inequality  $$P(| X^{}_n-0|\ge \varepsilon) \le \frac{E[|X|]}{\varepsilon} = \frac{n}{\varepsilon} \to \infty$$

Can I use Markov's inequality like this?
$$P(| X^{}_n-0|\ge \varepsilon) \le\frac{E[|X^{\frac{1}{4}}|]}{\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{4}}} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}\varepsilon} \to 0$$

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need Markov's inequality. For all $n > \sqrt{\epsilon}$ you have
$$P(|X_n - 0| \ge \epsilon) = P(X_n \ge \epsilon) = \frac{1}{n} \to 0.$$

Comment: But why $n>1/\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, shouldn't it be $n^2 \ge \varepsilon$ ?

Comment: @asdf My mistake, sorry. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you @angryavian.